# How to retrieve the row index from DataGridCellInfo

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have read scores of posts about this topic but none seem to address my specific issue.  I am using a wpf grid with vb behind.  Here is my event handler:

```
Private Sub dgrdMain_SelectedCellsChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs) Handles dgrMain.SelectedCellsChanged
    If e.RemovedCells.Count > 0 Then
        Dim ilRemovedCells As IList(Of DataGridCellInfo) = e.RemovedCells
        For Each rc As DataGridCellInfo In ilRemovedCells
            rc.Column.DisplayIndex   'This gives the column index
            'How do I get the row index?
        Next
    End If
```

Here rc=removed cell.  My question is the comment line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick function to return the index... let me know if this is what you need...

```
Public Shared Function GetRowIndex(dataGrid As DataGrid, dataGridCellInfo As DataGridCellInfo) As Integer
Dim dgrow As DataGridRow = DirectCast(dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGridCellInfo.Item), DataGridRow)
If dgrow IsNot Nothing Then
    Return dgrow.GetIndex()
    Else
    Return -1
End If

End Function
```